# Adding the same SceneNode to a SceneNodeGroupModel3D with HelixToolkit and SharpDX in C#

Tags: c#, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

I have a Viewport3DX binded to a ModelGroup (which is a SceneNodeGroupModel3D). In my case, I have to import an .obj file as a SceneNode and add it to the ModelGroup using the function ModelGroup.AddNode(node). I do it as it follows:

```
var importer = new Importer();
HelixToolkitScene scene = importer.Load("PathToTheModel");
ModelGroup.AddNode(scene.Root)
```

But as soon as I try to add the same SceneNode (because I want to import the same model but then place it in a different position), it doesn't work. In fact, the second `ModelGroup.AddNode(scene.Root)` will return false, because we alredy have such SceneNode in the SceneNodeGroupModel3D.

The solution I found is using again the importer, but I feel like it's not the way how to do it because once I loaded the model, it does not make sense reloading it, right?

As far as I saw, when you use the importer, the SceneNode is linked to a new GUID (globally unique identifier) and the function `.AddNode()` checks for the existing nodes of the SceneNodeGroupModel3D and in case of match, ignores the command. Then in case of using the same `scene.Root` just adds one, and if I import twice, I am able to get the two identical models in the group, but with differents GUIDs.

So, the question is how could add to SceneNode and a clone to the same SceneNodeGroupModel3D? I don't mind if it's modifying the GUIDs, clonning the whole SceneNode or any workaround you might suggest. For this example might be not a problem, but imagine if we have 1 model but 100 times, importing and loading the same model all the time would be a waste of resources.

Thanks in advance!